# Get String from bluetooth buffer

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an app to communicate with a PCB board via bluetooth.

I receive a string from the PCB board to my app every 50ms. This string has the next structure:

**start_byte(1byte)/battery _level(1byte)/speed(1byte)/mode(1byte)**

So I'll receive a string like this (I'll put it in hex):

**80464B11**

each 50ms.

This is the code. First this is the **ConnectedThread** which listens for the communication and that sends the received message to the mainActivity:

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int readed;

    while (true) {
        try {
            readed = inputStream.read(buffer);
            if (readed > 0) {
                final byte[] temp = new byte [readed];
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, temp, 0, readed);

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        /*Sends message to UI*/
                        connectionListener.msgRead(temp);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ...
            break;
        }
    }
```

Then in **MainActivity** I operate with the received string to extract from it each value.

```
@Override
public void msgRead(byte[] buffer) {
    String income = byteArrayToHex(buffer);
    ...
```

Here the next step would be to check for the start_byte and after this, get the other values.

But here comes my doubt. This string will be received each 50ms, so I'll be receiving something like this:

**80464B1180464B1180464B1180464B1180464B1180464B1180464B1180464B1180464B11...**

So, what I do to check for the start_byte is this:

```
String start_byte = income.substring(0,  2);
```

And then, if that matches with the start_byte value, I extract the rest of the values:

```
if (start_byte.equals("80")) {
    ...
```

Is my approach correct to face this? Won't the buffer overflow? How can I correctly check for the start_byte to the get the other values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the problem this way. I've created a Queue in the ConnectedThread. Each time I receive a byte[] I put it into the Queue.

```
LinkedList<Byte> dataQueue = new LinkedList<Byte>();

int i = 0;
while (i< temp.length) {
    dataQueue.add(temp[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Then, when I want to get them I do:

```
byte readed_byte = dataQueue.pop();
```

This way I get a byte from the head of the queue each time I do pop().

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is usefull to just use the `read()` function. This function is blocking until one byte has been read. So you can make something like this:

```
int[] yourArray = new int[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   yourArray[i] = inputStream.read();
}
```

so now your string is devived in 4 int's stored in a array.

maybe this helps you out in some sort of way